# How to replace an unknown string in multiple files under Linux?

Tags: string, replace, terminal

I want to change multiple different strings across all files in a folder to one new string.

When the string in the text files (within a same directory) is like this:

- *file1.json*: `"url/1.png"`
- *file2.json*: `"url/2.png"`
- *file3.json*: `"url/3.png"`
- etc.

I would need to point them all to a single PNG, i.e., `"url/static.png"`, so all three files have the same URL inside pointing to the same PNG.

How can I do that?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the command find and sed for this. make sure you are in the folder that you want to replace files.

```
find . -name '*.*' -print|xargs sed -i "s/\"url\/1.png\"/\"url\/static.png\"/g"
```

Comment: I actually solved it with this regexp

`sed -i 's/image[0-9]*\.png/static.png/g' *` but your answer was close enough! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggesting `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# for each file with extension .json in current directory
for currFile in *.json; do
  # extract files ordinal from from current filename
  filesOrdinal=$(echo "@currFile"| grep -o "[[:digit:]]\+")
  # use files ordinal to identify string and replace it in current file
  sed -i -r 's|url/'"$filesOrdinal".png'|url/static.png|' $currFile
done
```